Spring Security requireSecure infinite redirect
I'm trying to force https on my heroku web application that I've built using spring security and react.
I took some of the example code from this page: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/preparing-a-spring-boot-app-for-production-on-heroku#force-the-use-of-https
I'm running into an infinite redirection problem. Here is my security filter chain method:
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
        .addFilterBefore(captchaFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .authorizeHttpRequests(
            auth -> auth.requestMatchers("/", "/register", "/index.html", "/static/**", "/favicon.ico", "/manifest.json", "**.png").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
        .formLogin(form -> form.loginProcessingUrl("/perform_login")
            .loginPage("/")
            .successHandler(new AuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                    Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {}
            })
            .failureHandler(
                new AuthenticationFailureHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                            AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
                                response.setStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value());
                            }
                    
                }
            )
        )
        .requiresChannel(channel -> channel.anyRequest().requiresSecure())
        .csrf(csrf -> csrf.csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())   
            .csrfTokenRequestHandler(new SpaCsrfTokenRequestHandler())  )
        .addFilterAfter(new CsrfCookieFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .logout(logout -> logout.logoutUrl("/api/auth/logout")
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .logoutSuccessHandler(new LogoutSuccessHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                        Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {}
                
            }))
        
        .build();
    }

I've tried moving the "requiresSecure" around to various points, but I continue to get an infinite redirecting issue.
Does anyone know what's going on?
I was trying to force https, but I'm running into an infite loop.
